# Counting column values based on values in other columns for Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count the number of each category of storm for each unique `x` and `y` combination. For example. My dataframe looks like:

```
x   y  year  Category
1   1  1988     3
2   1  1977     1
2   1  1999     2
3   2  1990     4
```

I want to create a dataframe that looks like:

```
x   y   Category 1   Category 2   Category 3  Category 4
1   1        0           0            1           0
2   1        1           1            0           0
3   2        0           0            0           1
```

I have tried various combinations of `.groupby()` and `.count()`, but I am still not getting the desired result. The closet thing I could get is:

```
df[['x','y','Category']].groupby(['Category']).count()
```

However, the result counts for all `x` and `y`, not the unique pairs:

```
Cat       x           y     
1       3773         3773
2       1230         1230
3       604          604
4       266          266
5       50           50
NA      27620        27620
TS      16884        16884
```

Does anyone know how to do a count operation on one column based on the uniqueness of two other columns in a dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) sounds like what you want. A bit of a hack is to add a column of `1`'s to use to count. This allows `pivot_table` to add `1` for each occurrence of a particular `x`-`y` and `Category` combination. You will set this new column as your `value` parameter in `pivot_table` and the `aggfunc` paraemter to `np.sum`. You'll probably want to set `fill_value` to `0` as well:

```
df['count'] = 1
result = df.pivot_table(
    index=['x', 'y'], columns='Category', values='count',
    fill_value=0, aggfunc=np.sum
)
```

`result`:

```
Category  1  2  3  4
x y                 
1 1       0  0  1  0
2 1       1  1  0  0
3 2       0  0  0  1
```

---

If you're interested in keeping `x` and `y` as columns and having the other column names as `Category X`, you can rename the columns and use `reset_index`:

```
result.columns = [f'Category {x}' for x in result.columns]
result = a.reset_index()
```

Comment: That count column and aggfunc is pretty smart.

Comment: Thanks, I was kind of hoping someone would point out a cleaner way to do it though!

Comment: It's clean. But just explain why you used count = 1. Because other readers might get confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) first:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['x', 'y', 'Category']).count()
df_new
                  year  count
x   y   Category        
1   1      3       1    1
2   1      1       1    1
           2       1    1
3   2      4       1    1
```

Then [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
df_new = df_new.pivot_table(index=['x', 'y'], columns='Category', values='count', fill_value=0)
df_new
Category    1   2   3   4
x   y               
1   1       0   0   1   0
2   1       1   1   0   0
3   2       0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.get_dummies` after setting index using `set_index`, then use `sum` with `level` parameter to collapse rows:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['x','y'])['Category'].astype(str),
               prefix='Category ', 
               prefix_sep='')\
  .sum(level=[0,1])\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   x  y  Category 1  Category 2  Category 3  Category 4
0  1  1           0           0           1           0
1  2  1           1           1           0           0
2  3  2           0           0           0           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `groupby` twice, with a lot of additional, i.e `get_dummies` with `apply` etc...

Like:

```
>>> df.join(df.groupby(['x','y'])['Category']
           .apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.get_dummies().add_prefix('Category ')))
           .groupby(['x','y']).sum().fillna(0).drop(['year','Category'],1).reset_index()
   x  y  Category 1  Category 2  Category 3  Category 4
0  1  1         0.0         0.0         1.0         0.0
1  2  1         1.0         1.0         0.0         0.0
2  3  2         0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0
>>>
```

Comment: @MohitMotwani Done it.